# What is the default web server in Puppet enterprise

Tags: puppet

I have a question, it might be trivial, but I needed to check as I did not see an explicit information so far.

**What is the default web server in Puppet Enterprise 3.3.2?**

In all puppet lab documentation and in different forums, it is mentioned puppet uses WEBrick and one need to install Apache/Passenger or something similar to scale up.

Now my question is, is this applicable for Puppet Enterprise too. Because I can see the service it runs is **pe-httpd**.

So can I safely assume, I do not need to explicitly install Apache2 and say Passenger for scaling up [and those installations are needed only for open source puppet]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apache2 is the default webserver when puppet enterprise is in use.

I placed the question to another forum too, and got the reply. Adding the link here.
http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/14240/what-is-the-default-web-server-in-puppet-enterprise/